# Is it possible to get rid of iOS In App Purchase confirmation popup?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I get the "You are all set" system dialog after purchasing a subscription in my app. Just by chance, is it possible to get rid of it in order to show my own confirmation modal?

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, no. There is no way to replace the system dialog.